# How to get the Row and Column that a cloned image is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to show what Row and Column that a cloned image is in. For example if I want the drag the image to Row 1 Column 5, on dropping it there is it possible to have Row 1 Column 5 values be inputted into a memory array?

Also is it possible to drop the image in Row 1  Column 5 and set this as the state 'on' which would be inputted into a memory array?

```
<style>

#div1 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:200px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;border-color: white white white black;}
#div2 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:300px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;border-color: white white white white;}
#div3 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:400px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;border-color: white white white white;}
#div4 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:500px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #000000;border-color: white white white white;}
#div5 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:600px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #000000;border-color: white white white white;}
#div6 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:700px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;border-color: white white white white;}
#div7 {position:absolute;width:100px;height:25px;top:150px;left:800px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;border-color: white black white white;

</style>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));}
</script>



<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
<div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div

</body>

<img id="drag1" src="bat.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"    width="100" height="25" align="center">
 <img id="drag2" src="ball.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="25" align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i need a bit more specific information but, this should get you in the right direction:

Basically on the `drop` function, you want to push your target values (in this case the `div1, div2 etc`) divs into an array as objects

```
var memoryArray = [];


function drop(ev) {
var _target = ev.target;
    var targetId = _target.getAttribute('id');
    var elem = document.getElementById(targetId)
    setTimeout(function(){
       var imgSrc = elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;      
       var object = {
                    id:elem.id ,
              image: imgSrc

       }
       memoryArray.push(object)
       console.log(memoryArray)

    }, 20)
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

There are many ways to achieve this, this is just one.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91xf4b1/)